# How can i hide model Dialog on performing Action?

Tags: dialog, botframework

I'm trying to figure out a way if i can hide the intermediate dialog(shown in image below) and simply redirect to download a file ?

[image]

**Sample.Json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [       
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This card's action will open a URL"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "url": "https://adaptivecards.io", //i'll have my file path in cloud to download
            "style": "destructive"
        }
    ]
}
```

To test use the above Json copied to this url https://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Bot%20Framework%20WebChat

Comment: It looks like you've only tested this in the visualizer. What application will end up rendering your Adaptive Card?

Comment: i run it locally using bot framework emulator. looks like the confirmation window on `openUrl` goes away when its on server but it stays when i run it locally.

Comment: Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: well temporarily yes @KyleDelaney as i don't see a way to remove that when i run it locally. do you see the same behavior ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with running it locally. Like all card actions, OpenUrl actions are performed by the client application and are thus channel-specific. Your bot has no control over this behavior. Since I assume you don't expect your customers to be talking to your bot through the Emulator, why is this behavior only "temporarily" acceptable to you?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: that's right! @KyleDelaney customer will not be talking via emulator we use that for testing bot. luckily when we deploy it & test it i not longer see the confirm popup it launches the URL in browser directly. as it's happening only when i'm testing its kind off ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something your bot has control over, and it will not affect your customers anyway. If you still want a way to configure this behavior in Emulator, you can make a feature request in the [Emulator repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues).

The Adaptive Cards visualizer is just the old version of the designer so they almost definitely won't be making changes to that, and it's just meant to give feedback rather than perform actual actions.